# Can't run a valid MySQL query

Tags: mysql, r

I have code in R that is supposed to generate and run an INSERT query into a local MySQL database. The connection works, as I'm able to run a couple other queries, so I know that the connection, and my methodology should be working. I'm also printing out the query I'm trying, and then I paste in to my MySQL connection and it works, so I don't know why R is throwing an error. What can I do to fix this?

The query:

```
INSERT INTO Strike SET effect =  '' , feet_above_ground =  '0' ; SET @Strike_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); Insert INTO Flight SET date =  '1/1/00 0:00' , aircraft_type =  'Airplane' , record_id =  '200508' , strike_id = @Strike_id , airport_id = (SELECT id FROM Airport WHERE name =  'NEWARK LIBERTY INTL ARPT' ), airline_id = (SELECT id FROM Airline WHERE name =  'CONTINENTAL AIRLINES' ); UPDATE Strike SET flight_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = @Strike_id;
```

The code:

```
padValue <- function(value) {
    return(paste('"',value,'"', sep=""))
}
insertFlightAndStrike <- function(data, connection=con) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
        row <- data[i,]
        effect = padValue(row$Effect..Impact.to.flight)
        feet_above_ground = padValue(row$Feet.above.ground)
        flight_date = padValue(row$FlightDate)
        aircraft_type = padValue(row$Aircraft..Type)
        record_id = padValue(row$Record.ID)
        airport_name = padValue(row$Airport..Name)
        airline_name = padValue(row$Aircraft..Airline.Operator)
        query <- paste("INSERT INTO Strike SET effect = ",effect,
            ", feet_above_ground = ",feet_above_ground,
            "; SET @Strike_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO Flight SET date = ", flight_date,
            ", aircraft_type = ", aircraft_type,
            ", record_id = ", record_id,
            ", strike_id = @Strike_id",
            ", airport_id = (SELECT id FROM Airport WHERE name = ", airport_name,
            "), airline_id = (SELECT id FROM Airline WHERE name = ", airline_name,");",
            "UPDATE Strike SET flight_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = @Strike_id;")
        print(gsub("\"","'",query))
        dbGetQuery(connection, gsub("\"","'",query))
    }
}
```

The error:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @Strike_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); Insert INTO Flight SET date = '1/1/00 0:00' ' at line 1

Edit:

When trying to use the query in MySQL:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Strike SET effect =  '' , feet_above_ground =  '0' ; SET @Strike_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO Flight SET date =  '1/1/00 0:00' , aircraft_type =  'Airplane' , record_id =  '200508' , strike_id = @Strike_id , airport_id = (SELECT id FROM Airport WHERE name =  'NEWARK LIBERTY INTL ARPT' ), airline_id = (SELECT id FROM Airline WHERE name =  'CONTINENTAL AIRLINES' ); UPDATE Strike SET flight_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = @Strike_id;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
      could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @Strike_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); Insert INTO Flight SET date =  '1/1/00 0:00' ' at line 1

Comment: Look at the error message and note the extra single quote in the date.

Comment: The extra single quote is inserted by R's error console, notice it's not there in the generated query

Comment: Well, to be fair, I _can't_ look at the generated query, because your code isn't reproducible. I can't even run it enough to generate the query string. Either way, sorry I don't know exactly what's going on.

Comment: The generated query is in my post, it's the first block of code

Comment: So you say, and I'll give you the benefit of the doubt, but long experience of answering questions here teaches you that question askers are very, very, very often wrong about things like that. (Not that you are, it's just that 99 times out of 100, someone will swear up and down that their code produces X, and then once they provide something reproducible it turns out it actually produces Y. So you learn to be suspicious.)

Comment: I definitely understand that, however, look at the last part of my updated post: I copy and pasted the output of my print statement into MySQL and the query worked. @joran

Comment: I'm not arguing, I'm just explaining my initial mistrust, that's all. Just out of curiosity, can you successfully run each semicolon delimited piece of the query from R in isolation? i.e. just `'INSERT INTO Strike SET effect =  '' , feet_above_ground =  '0'`, and then the next statement, etc.?

Comment: @joran somehow, that fixed everything! If you submit an answer, then I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql> SET @Strike_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Works for me.

Comment: That doesn't work, and doesn't really make sense. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html